# Find out when ioredis connection has been established

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm using ioredis module.

```
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();
```

On doing `new Redis()` a connection is established to the redis server, how can I find out when this connection established? some callback perhaps?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can listen for the [`connect` event](https://github.com/luin/ioredis#connection-events):

```
redis.on('connect', function () { /* do something */ });
```

You can also use the [`connect(callback)` method](https://github.com/luin/ioredis/blob/master/API.md#redisconnectcallback--promise):

```
redis.connect(function () { /* Do your stuff */ });
```

The latter also returns a promise if you prefer that.